# Is there any way to make Windows use my manual brightness setting all the time?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, power-management, brightness

Windows maintains two brightness sliders per profile (on battery and plugged in). This means I almost always have to readjust brightness using the Fn keys whenever I plug the AC adapter in or remove it.

Is there any way to prevent Windows from ever overriding my manual brightness setting?

Answer (score 0):

[ClickMonitorDDC](http://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net/) appears to be capable of doing this. There's a "Same laptop-brightness for battery and plugged" option, visible in [this screenshot](http://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net/general.png).